# Merge similar text html cell of first row using Jquery excluding header

Tags: jquery, html

I have a html table with columns as "`Name`","`Location`","`ContactNo`". I want to merge only "`Name`" column having similar text in the row using `Jquery`. Hence if I have 4 rows in the table as below

### Name

John

Bill

John

Bill

Then I want to merge `1st` with `3rd` and `2nd` with `4th` and so on. This is just an example. It can have many rows. I was thinking to sort first and then merge. Can you please tell me how to achieve by either sort and merge OR one single function to merge.

Answer (score 1):

Something like that should work :

```
var mergedData = {}
$("#yourtable tbody tr").each(function(index, element){
    var item = $(element);
    var Name = item.children("td:nth-child(1)").text();
    var Location = item.children("td:nth-child(2)").html();
    var ContactNo = item.children("td:nth-child(3)").html();

    if(mergedData[Name] === undefined) {
        mergedData[Name] = {Name :Name, Location : Location, ContactNo : ContactNo};
    }
    else {
        mergedData[Name].Name += Name;
        mergedData[Name].Location += Location;
        mergedData[Name].ContactNo += ContactNo;
    }
});

$("#yourtable tbody").empty();

$.each(mergedData, function(){
    var item = $(this)
    $("#yourtable tbody").append("<tr>" +
                                 "<td>" + item.Name + "</td>" + 
                                 "<td>" + item.Location + "</td>" + 
                                 "<td>" + item.ContactNo + "</td>" + 
                                 "</tr>");
});
```